# Reg safe boot mode in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bootloader, password-recovery, login-screen

I just recently stuck with safe boot login window.I entered into safe via msconfig win win10,after restart, it enters into safe mode.

I'm using 4 digit pin for user login password,and I'm the admin. I tried using the pin but says incorrect password, I tried microsoft account pwd also but no use.

I'm stuck in the login window.There is not even forget pwd option.Is there any option to come out of this crap via boot options like f12 ,I'm also trying my best.

Comment: What are you actually asking? It seems as though you're presenting 3 or 4 different problems, but none of them are very clearly or concisely presented. Please edit your post to focus on a single question and make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can get a command prompt. 
by pressing F8 F2 F12 or another one (maybe also via lenovo button on the side of the pc you need a paper clip if you have a lenovo)
Or with a system repair disk,
the primary goal is to get a terminal, then it's almost won.

Windows 10 Advanced Startup Options(screen blue)
Troubleshooting.
Advanced options.
Command prompt.
when the command prompt is finally accessible passes one of these lines
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy standard
or
bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot

then removes this secure start in msconfig
I hope you have good luck.

Comment: You can change your Microsoft Account password in the Microsoft Account Login website. Did you try that?

Comment: when the pc boot in safe mode via msconfig it is not by changing the password that it will change anything, it will always boot in safe mode as long as the option in msconfig has not been restored.

Comment: Yes that's what the problem here,I tried all the function key combinations but in vain, no one showing cmd prompt window, now gonna flash the drive using iso and trying to trouble shoot

Comment: I think that it does not remain you as you say it, the solution of the dvd of repair to reach the command line and to pass the commands quoted above to stop this cycle bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy standard or                                              bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot.

Comment: ive flashed my usb with iso of win 10 and went to cmd dialog box but it didnt work,so i just delete the old OS and flashed new,this is second in this year for me;-(